# Vue 3 prop issue

Tags: json, vue.js

i have an api that returns some json with a list of vendors and i want to pass an array of just the names of the items in the json into a sfc vue component as a prop.

for some reason this isnt working and i dont know why

the parent component should be passing in the array of vendor names in to the child component to be used as the options for a dropdown menu

parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="title">Catalog</h1>
    <dtable v-bind:tableData="products" v-bind:vendors="vendor_names"></dtable>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import dtable from "../components/dataTable.vue"

export default {

  components: {
    dtable,
  },
  data: () => ({
    vendors: [],
    vendor_names: [],
  }),

  methods: {
    loadVendors() {
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendors.json")
        .then(response => (this.vendors = response.data))
    },
    get_vendor_names() {
      this.vendor_names = this.vendors.map(vname => { return vname.name })
      console.log("vendor names", this.vendor_names)

    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.loadVendors()
    this.get_vendor_names()
  }
}

</script>
```

child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <DataTable :value="tableData" editMode="row" dataKey="id" v-model:editingRows="editingRows"
      
      <Column field="sku" header="SKU" style="width:10%" :sortable="true">
        <template #editor="{ data, field }">
          <InputText v-model="data[field]" autofocus />
        </template>
      </Column>

      <Column field="name" header="Name" style="width:30%" :sortable="true">
        <template #editor="{ data, field }">
          <InputText v-model="data[field]" />
        </template>
      </Column>

      <Column field="description" header="Description" style="width:30%">
        <template #editor="{ data, field }">
          <InputText v-model="data[field]" />
        </template>
      </Column

      <Column field="brand" header="Vendors" style="width:20%" :sortable="true">
        <template #editor="{ data, field }">
          <Dropdown v-model="data[field]" :options="vendors" optionValue="value" placeholder="Select a Brand">
          </Dropdown>
        </template>
      </Column>

      <Column field="price" header="Price" style="width:20%" :sortable="true">
        <template #editor="{ data, field }">
          <InputText v-model="data[field]" />
        </template>
      </Column>
      <Column :rowEditor="true" style="width:10%; min-width:8rem" bodyStyle="text-align:center"></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: [
    'tableData',
    'vendors'
  ],

  data() {
    return {
      selectedProducts: null,
      editingRows: [],

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

my JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "description": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
        "description": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "name3",
        "description": "test"
    }
]
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: my console.log results in: Proxy {}

Comment: You are not waiting for the `loadVendors` call, so when you call `get_vendor_names()` the vendors array is probably still empty. I suggest you make `vendor_names` a computed property, so it updates when `vendors` changes.

Comment: you are passing "produtcs" to the child component.. there is no such variable

Comment: products is a different thing im passing in, i just forgot to remove that before i posted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to @Gabe

making it a computed property worked like a charm

> You are not waiting for the loadVendors call, so when you call
> get_vendor_names() the vendors array is probably still empty. I
> suggest you make vendor_names a computed property, so it updates when
> vendors changes.